AWS cloudwatch log alarm which steps should I be looking at
I have a log file that contains messages from multiple cameras. Below is a snip from one camera that shows it going offline and then coming back online.
2024-11-15 13:10:11.234+00:00 [   167] WARNING    - bdab-b307-4df3-8596  CameraDecoder (testc00013.test0001ev) - Camera 1  Device communication error (NoDataException). Error: GetMediaDataBlock returned no data.

2024-11-15 13:10:18.602+00:00 [   167] INFO       - bdab-b307-4df3-8596  CameraDecoder (testc00013.test0001ev) - Camera 1  Device communication established

The unique cameraid is testc00013.test0001ev and the offline string is Device communication error and online is Device communication established
What I would like to do is create and alarm for each camera if it goes offline and doesn't come back online within 5 mins. I've looked at creating a log insight and metric filters but I cannot understand how I can use those feature to achieve an alarm for each unique cameraid ? I need to understand the steps should be looking at to achieve my outcome.
